# how to extract data from different sheets using =IFERROR(INDEX in multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Problem:**

I'm trying to find an answer to this as online I've found that VBA is best solutions to this problem which has helped me pulling data from single sheet but still there are some problems while fetching values for same cell value from different sheets.

[Result File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDlsP.jpg)[Master_File_Access_point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyiJh.jpg)
[Master_File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrqN0.jpg)

**What I've tried:**

Master file is a kind of a stock inventory, where data is distributed on several sheets category wise. I have done trying fetching the data from single sheet of the master file successfully. For this what I have done is as below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point'!$A$1:$I$500,SMALL(IF('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point'!$A$1:$A$500=$B$3,ROW('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point'!$A$1:$A$500)),ROW(1:20)),2,1),"")
```

**What I want to do is:**

I trying to pull data in results from every sheet given in master file for $B$3.
When I enter the path for multiple sheets using 3D reference as

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point:Adapter Laptop & TFT'!$A$1:$I$500,SMALL(IF('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point:Adapter Laptop & TFT'!$A$1:$A$500=$B$3,ROW('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point:Adapter Laptop & TFT'!$A$1:$A$500)),ROW(1:20)),2,1),"")
```

it doesn't shows any results.

Comment: Will there only ever be a single result? Or could it find a match on more than one sheet?

Comment: there could be more results from more than one sheet.

Comment: You could just write a lookup formula for each sheet and then concatenate the results using & . So IFERROR(INDEX('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point'!....)&IFERROR(INDEX('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Adapter Laptop & TFT'!...) etc

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, that's helpful but what if i want to put the results after the results fetching from sheet 'Access Point' is completed.

Answer (score 0):

The same has been answered by Harassed Dad, however which is in unanswered history. Hence posting answer behalf of Harassed Dad, which has accepted by question owner.

You could just write a `lookup` formula for each sheet and then `concatenate` the results using `&` . So `IFERROR(INDEX('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point'!....)&IFERROR(INDEX('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Adapter Laptop & TFT'!...)` etc...

Comment: **After few attempts** 

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx'!tbl_1, SMALL(IF(($B$3='[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point'!$A$4:$A$500), ROW('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point'!$A$4:$A$500)-MIN(ROW('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point'!$A$4:$A$500))+1, ""), ROW(A1)), 2), INDEX('Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx'!tbl_2, SMALL(IF(($B$3='[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Adapter 18V'!$A$4:$A$500), ROW('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Adapter 18V'!$A$4:$A$500)-MIN(ROW('[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Adapter 18V'!$A$4:$A$500))+1, ""), ROW(A1)-SUM(--($B$3='[Stock_Book_MU CSD.xlsx]Access Point'!$A$4:$A$500))), 2))`

Comment: Above is helping in fetching data from **Two sheets** in desired results, but how to fetch data from more than two or more sheets???